# "else if" in jQuery wasn't performed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use magic line jquery navigation effect both horizontal and vertical menu at the same time.
http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

```
$(function() {  var $el, leftPos, topPos;
```

I chose default region for my effect

```
$("#region-top-left").append("< li id='magic-line'></ li >");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
```

I defined first statement - when i hover something in main horizontal menu

```
            {

                $magicLine
                    .css("left", $('.active').position().left)

                .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)

                ('.menu').find('li').hover(function () {

                    $el = $(this);
                    leftPos = $el.position().left;
                    magicLine.stop().animate({
                        left: leftPos,
                    });
                }, function () {
                    $magicLine.stop().animate({
                        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),

                    });
                });
            }
```

and if i hover something in the navigation vertical menu

```
            else if ('#vertical-menu:hover')
```

do that

```
             {
                $magicLine
                    .css("top", $('.active').position().top)
                    .data("origTop", $magicLine.position().top)


                $('.menu').find('li').hover(function () {
                    $el = $(this);
                    topPos = $el.position().top;


                    $magicLine.stop().animate({
                        top: topPos,

                    });
                }, function () {
                    $magicLine.stop().animate({
                        top: $magicLine.data("origTop"),

                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

But works only the first condition. What should i do?
Any help will be appreciated.

**Update.**
Thank for your help **dave** and **Evan**.
Now my code looks like that

```
(function ($) {
```

this is for

```
Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
```

drupal

```
var $el, leftPos, topPos;
$("#region-top-left").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
```

**.on('hover',function()**
didn't work

```
$('#horizontal-menu').hover(function() {
$magicLine
.css("left", $('.active').position().left)
.data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)


$('.menu').find('li').hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;


    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,

    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),

    });
 }
 );});


  $('#vertical-menu').hover(function() {
    $magicLine

    .css("top", $('.active').position().top)
    .data("origTop", $magicLine.position().top)


  $('.menu').find('li').hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    topPos = $el.position().top;


        $magicLine.stop().animate({
        top: topPos,

         });
          }, function() {
     $magicLine.stop().animate({
        top: $magicLine.data("origTop"),

              });
           });
         });
        }   
     };   
   })
(jQuery);
```

and it works. Yay!

Comment: Stack Overflow tip - Code blocks should be indented with four spaces - the `>` is used for block quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
if ('#horizontal-menu:hover')
```

Should be

```
$('#horizontal-menu').on('hover',function() {
//code goes here
});
```

This

```
if ('#vertical-menu:hover')
```

Should be

```
$('#vertical-menu').on('hover',function() {
//code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an `else if`, just create the two events and jQuery will handle the rest for you

```
$('.menu').find('li').on('hover', function() {
    // code here ...
});

$('#another').on('hover', function(){
    // more code here...
});
```